# How do i fetch the text which is a part of grandparent?

Tags: selenium

How do i fetch the name "JAFFERYI ADI" from the following html code? Have to fetch the name within for loop  every time name will be different only the word 'years' will be common.  I tried with

```
"driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='patient-slide-header']/div[contains(text(), 'years')]"
```

but found NoSUchELementException. Please help. Here is the html DOM

```
<div class="patient-slide-header" style="" xpath="1">
    <div class="patient-slide-header patient-slide-header-h2" style="">
        <a onclick="objPatientDetail.NavigatePatient('backward');" href="#" class="prev-patient patient-details-navigation" style=""></a>
        JAFFERYI ADI (56 years)
    <div class="patient-slide-header-details"></div>
    <a onclick="objPatientDetail.NavigatePatient('forward');" class="next-patient patient-details-navigation" href="#" style=""></a>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnHIEurl">
</div>
```

Comment: I think this should work `//div[@class='patient-slide-header']/div`

Comment: //div[@class='patient-slide-header']/div.getText() has given other texts as well which contains by <a> and <div> tag.

Comment: Do you want 56 years or not?

Comment: Name is important, years is optional.

Comment: Can you share the whole string that you are getting?

Comment: okay, let me execute it.

Comment: <div class="paent-slide-header patient-slide-header-h2" xpath="1">
 <a onclick="objPatient.NaviPatient('backward');" href="#" class="prev-patient patient-details-navigation">
 <div>
  << PREV
 </div></a>
 JAFFERYI ADI (56 years)
<div class="patient-slide-header-details">
 <span class="patient-slide-header-spacer">
  Female </span>
 <span class="patient-slide-header-spacer">
  DOB:3/14/1983</span>
 <span class="patient-slide-header-spacer"></span>
</div>
<a onclick="objPatientDetail.NavigatePatient('forward');" class="next-patient patient-details-navigation" href="#"></a>
</div>

Comment: The above code will give you more idea. Its printing  all text PREV, Female, DOB etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this-

```
String Name=  //div[@class='patient-slide-header']/div.getText().substring(6, 28);
System.out.Println(Name);
```

Change sub string characters according to your need.

Comment: Hey Amruta, Thanks it worked for me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

String xpath = //div[@class='patient-slide-header-h2']

String value = diver.findelememt(By.xpath(xpath).getText();
String[] myName = value.split("(");

Value = myName[0].trim();

Comment: String value=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath).getText(); --.getText() method not found for this statement and stored value into WebElement and then .getText() method worked  and when executed its giving me an error at String[] statement. Thanks.

Comment: (By.xpath(xpath)).getText();